# looping date function php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have table name "guest_room" in database, the fields of guest_room are "arrival" and "departure", the value of arrival is "2016-12-27" and the value of departure is "2016-12-31".

in my php file I want to show data from arrival to departure date, here my code :

```
$date = $g[arrival];
$end_date = $g[departure];
while (strtotime($date) <= strtotime($end_date)) {                                       
$date = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)));
echo "$date<br>";
}
```

but in my result show the date from "2016-12-28" until "2017-01-01"
what I want is, I want to show the date from "2016-12-27" until "2016-12-31"

I know I shouldn't use mysql_ but this is no point, help me please

Comment: Just... switch the two lines inside your loop? (ie. incrementing **after** you output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put your incrementation at the end of your loops body:

```
$date = $g[arrival];
$end_date = $g[departure];
while (strtotime($date) <= strtotime($end_date)) {                                       
    // Switched these lines so the increment is at the end of the body
    echo "$date<br>";
    $date = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)));
}
```

Comment: Ofcourse it does, why wouldn't it? Edit: [See eval'ed output](http://ideone.com/oRn8eA)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
$date =  "2016-12-27" ;
$end_date = "2016-12-31";
while (strtotime($date) <= strtotime($end_date)) {
    echo "$date<br>";
    $date = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)));
}
```

Comment: That still would start at `2016-12-28` since you also increment before outputting...

Comment: hi it works but still wrong, the result from your code show start "2016-12-28" until "2016-12-30"

Comment: what are the dates you are expecting? output1: 27,28,29,30,31 op2: 27,28,29,30?

Comment: $date =  "2016-12-27" ;
$end_date = "2016-12-31";

so will show 
2016-12-27
2016-12-28
2016-12-29
2016-12-30
2016-12-31

Comment: Then this should be the fine answer. `$date =  "2016-12-27" ;
$end_date = "2016-12-31";
while (strtotime($date) <= strtotime($end_date)) {
echo "$date<br>";
$date = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)));
}`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$date = $g[arrival];
$end_date = $g[departure];
while (strtotime($date) < strtotime($end_date)) {                                       
$date = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)));
echo "$date<br>";
}
```

Comment: Same as OPs and @Naga's solution: Would still start 1 day late (ie. 2016-12-28 as in the example above)

Answer (score 0):

/**
 * Generate an array of string dates between 2 dates
 *
 * @param string $start Start date
 * @param string $end End date
 * @param string $format Output format (Default: Y-m-d)
 *
 * @return array
 */

```
function getDatesFromRange($start, $end, $format = 'Y-m-d') {
    $array = array();
    $interval = new DateInterval('P1D');

    $realEnd = new DateTime($end);
    $realEnd->add($interval);

    $period = new DatePeriod(new DateTime($start), $interval, $realEnd);

    foreach($period as $date) { 
        $array[] = $date->format($format); 
    }

    return $array;
}
```

Then, you would call the function as expected:

```
getDatesFromRange('2010-10-01', '2010-10-05');
```

Comment: Will work fine, might be a bit over the top considering he just has to put the incrementation at the end of his loop and be done with it. (You wouldn't do `while($i <= 10) { $i++; echo $i; }` instead of `while($i <= 10) { echo $i; $i++;  }` would you?)

Answer (score 0):

Simply echo date first and then increment the date

```
while (strtotime($date) <= strtotime($end_date)){
    echo "$date<br>";
    $date = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$date =  "2016-12-27";
$end_date = "2016-12-31";
while (strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)) <= strtotime($end_date)) {  
    echo "$date<br>";
    $date = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)));

}
echo "$date<br>";
```

**check screenshot**
[image]